# System.String in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, string, xamarin, uwp

From where does the reference of the `System.String` is being done in UWP application projects?

I got this question as I have a `String.Replace` method option [Replace(String, String, StringComparison)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-2.0#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_StringComparison_) in any Android app projects which is referring in Xamarin.Android and same way in iOS app project referring Xamarin.iOS as well.

But, in case of UWP, I am not able to get the same behaviour of `String.Replace`

**EDIT :**

Adding to the question based on the comment that UWP is using .NET Core, is there is any documentation on which .NET Core version each of the UWP/Windows SDK version is using? Because, this option of `String.Replace` is something new in .NET Core 2.0 and above as I can understand from Microsoft Docs of the same as quoted above in link.

Comment: UWP using dotnet core

Comment: @lindexi, thanks for the comment.. is there any info available on which version of .Net Core used by each of UWP SDK version? this feature of `String.Replace` is something new from .Net Core 2.0.

Comment: From what I know, UWP is not using .NET Core. As far as I remember it is based on .NET Standard.

Comment: @lindexi @Ryukote, thanks for your inputs. After some trials, i could get this option for my `String.Replace` function if I am referring SDK version of 16299 (Fall Creators Update) for Target and Min version of SDK in the UWP app. SDK version of 16299 is referring `String.Replace` from the library available in package `C:\Users\UserName\.nuget\packages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.4\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.dll`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some trials, what I can understand is UWP is using .NET core internally for some things at least from **Fall Creators Update (16299) of UWP SDK**.

The above mentioned way of `String.Replace()` function signature is something available in a project which is targeting UWP SDK version of Fall Creators Update (16299), but not any SDK version below that.

But, .NET Core reference of UWP SDK is not something I could see anywhere officially mentioned in docs by Microsoft.